# I am trying to use redux in my project and I am have a problem with call a function that using dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

app.js

```
import {fetchUser} from '../redux/action/index'
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

  const counter = useSelector(store => store.userState.currentUser)
  

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    fetchUser();
    console.log(counter)
  }, []);
```

calling for fetchUser.js

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import {USER_STATE_CHANGE} from '../constants/index'

export function fetchUser() {
  return( async(dispatch)=>{
    console.log('dssd')
    firebase.firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then(
          (snapshot)=>{
          if(snapshot.exists){
            dispatch({type: USER_STATE_CHANGE , currentUser : snapshot.data()})
            }
            else{
            console.log('error_fitchUser')
      }});
  })
}
```

user.js

```
import {USER_STATE_CHANGE} from '../constants/index'


const initialState={
    currentUse:null,
}

export const user=(state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
            return{
                ...state,
                currentUser:action.currentUser,
            }
        default:
            return({})
    }
    
}
```

the problem is that I don't Know how to send dispatch when calling for fetchUser
.........................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you've already added your asynchronous action middleware to your store. You can use the `useDispatch` react-redux hook and wrap your calls to your `fetchData` and `fetchUser` action creators with a call to `dispatch`. The middleware will handle passing `dispatch` to the asynchronous action.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchData());
  dispatch(fetchUser());
}, []);
```